# How to manage event ID when updating recurring events

Tags: python, google-calendar-api, recurring-events

I am getting every 5 minutes all changes that happened on my google calendar:

```py
res = service.events().list(calendarId='primary', showDeleted=True,
                            maxResults=1000, singleEvents=True,
                            timeMin=now, timeMax=limit,
                            pageToken=page_token).execute()
```

When, in my calendar, I update all recurring events, I receive, from the API, that each events have been cancelled and then updated with a new ID (containing the timestamp).

**Cancelled Events:**

20fvo81df80plt66dm1ju7a6ae_20190704T193000Z
20fvo81df80plt66dm1ju7a6ae_20190801T193000Z
20fvo81df80plt66dm1ju7a6ae_20190905T193000Z
20fvo81df80plt66dm1ju7a6ae_20191003T193000Z
20fvo81df80plt66dm1ju7a6ae_20191107T203000Z

**Updated Events:**

20fvo81df80plt66dm1ju7a6ae_20190704T190000Z 
20fvo81df80plt66dm1ju7a6ae_20190801T190000Z
20fvo81df80plt66dm1ju7a6ae_20190905T190000Z
20fvo81df80plt66dm1ju7a6ae_20191003T190000Z
20fvo81df80plt66dm1ju7a6ae_20191107T200000Z

These are the same events, but their id have changed.

I must match the cancelled event and the created one to update my own database.

I did not see any data in the updated events that could allow me to link them to the cancelled events.

Do you have any idea how I could handle that?

Thanks :)